# Ошибка вывода результата PL/SQL блока через DBMS_SQL.return_result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

При выполнении в Oracle APEX команды:

```
DECLARE
    first_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN first_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM employees;
    DBMS_SQL.return_result(first_cursor);
END;
```

строка `DBMS_SQL.return_result(first_cursor);`
выдает ошибку:

> Error processing condition. Error computing plan for statement.
> ORA-00905: missing keyword

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что непонятно, где запускается блок. Следует учесть, что возвращаемый  результат обрабатывается в клиенте. Tо есть, клиент должен неявно вызывать `GET_NEXT_RESULT`, обрабатывать результат и обеспечивать его вывод.

Блок из вопроса без каких либо изменений прекрасно работает, например, в SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      first_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3  BEGIN
  4      OPEN first_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM employees;
  5      DBMS_SQL.return_result(first_cursor);
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

        ID       DEPT     SALARY BEGIN_DAT END_DATE      MAN_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
         1         22    3500.86 01-JUL-19 01-MAY-20          1
         1         24    2000.86 01-JUN-19 01-MAY-20          2
         2         23    3500.86 01-JUN-19 01-MAY-20          2
         3         24    3500.86 01-JUN-19 01-MAY-20          3
         4         22    2000.86 01-JUN-19 01-MAY-20          3
         7         21    3500.86 01-MAY-19 01-MAY-20          1

6 rows selected.
```

Что эквивалентно явному возврату открытого курсора:

```
set autoprint on 
var rc refcursor
DECLARE
    first_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN first_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM employees;
    :rc := first_cursor;
END;
/
```

Comment: Запускаю в среде https://apex.oracle.com/en/, выдает ошибку, как указал выше. На вкладке Results выдает Error processing condition, на вкладке Explain выдает Error computing plan for statement.
ORA-00905: missing keyword . Просто я никогда не работал с PL/SQL и, тем более, в Apex. Но возникла необходимость. Данный код взял по образцу и там работало, а у меня выдает ошибку.

Comment: Вы действительно запускаете в версии 20.2?

Comment: А какая конкретно необходимость у вас возникла? Почему вы выбрали неявный возврат результата, а не через параметр, как обычно?

Comment: Проверил - нет, не в 20.2. VERSION:       18.0.0.0.0
COMPATIBILITY: 18.0.0.0

Comment: А в какой, и какая веерсия БД?

Comment: Возникла необходимость просто вывести все записи из таблицы. В обычном sql это делается в одну строчкy SELECT * FROM table. Для pl/sql нигде не мог найти понятный ответ. Вот что нашел, то и попробовал. Версию БД не знаю, я на их портале все делаю.

Comment: Apex у меня сейчас не стоит, нет возможности сейчас проверить. На [LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:8537262252112::NO:RP::) (там Apex) тоже не работает.   Сейчас, добавлю в ответ обычный способ возврата результата запроса.

Comment: Да у меня Apex тоже не стоит, я на их ресурсе залогинился развернул БД заданным скриптом и все. Пробую элементарную команду и тут такой облом )))

Comment: То что вы пробуете, это не элементарно, потому что не стандарт.